# Computed primary key doesn't get updated in EF Core entity after insert

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a special case where the Id of the table is defined as a computed column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [BusinessArea](
    [Id]  AS (isnull((CONVERT([nvarchar],[CasaId],(0))+'-')+CONVERT([nvarchar],[ConfigurationId],(0)),'-')) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [CasaId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConfigurationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BusinessArea] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Usually when I have a computed column i configure it like this:

```
builder.Entity<MyEntity>()
 .Property(p => p.MyComputed).HasComputedColumnSql(null);
```

With `.HasComputedColumnSql()` the value of MyComputed is reflected an insert/update on the entity.

However this trick doesn't work if the computed column is a PK.

Any idea on how to make that work also with a PK?

Comment: Why not have a compound PK of CasaId and ConfigurationId instead?

Comment: Can you show the code for BusinessArea entity configuration (Fluent API)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be made to work, but only for insert, by setting property [BeforeSaveBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableproperty.beforesavebehavior?view=efcore-2.1) to [Ignore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.propertysavebehavior?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_PropertySaveBehavior_Ignore):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessArea>().Property(e => e.Id)
    .Metadata.BeforeSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
```

But in general such design will cause problems with EF Core because it doesn't support mutable keys (primary or alternate). Which means that it would never retrieve back the `Id` from database after update. You can verify that by marking the property as [ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_PropertyBuilder_1_ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate) (which is the normal behavior for computed columns):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessArea>().Property(e => e.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

If you do so, EF Core will throw `InvalidOperationException` saying

> The property 'Id' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate' or 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate' because the key value cannot be changed after the entity has been added to the store.